# A json I have putted in a html element attribute has quite different data during reviewing from the attribute

Tags: javascript, attributes

In short , I need to put a json in an html element attribute to get it later.
Having done that I am starting to review that json but there are only some numbers instead keys and values.

Here is the json :

```
{Type: "gotWeather", Days: [,…]}
Days: [,…]
0: {Sections: [{Temperature: 280.55, Description: "scattered clouds", Time: 
"21:00:00", Icon: "03n"}],…}
1: {Sections: [{Temperature: 278.98, Description: "scattered clouds", Time: 
"00:00:00", Icon: "03n"},…],…}
2: {Sections: [{Temperature: 282.57, Description: "overcast clouds", Time: 
"00:00:00", Icon: "04n"},…],…}
3: {,…}
4: {Sections: [{Temperature: 285.953, Description: "light rain", Time: 
"00:00:00", Icon: "10n"},…],…}
5: {Sections: [{Temperature: 280.9, Description: "light rain", Time: 
"00:00:00", Icon: "10n"},…],…}
Type: "gotWeather"
```

In according with the code below I am putting :

```
socket.onmessage = function(evt){
   var json = JSON.parse(evt.data);
   weatherAnswer(json);
}

function weatherAnswer(json){
   // ...
   var buttons = prepareButtons(json);
}

function prepareButtons(json){
   var buttonsList = document.createElement("ul");
   buttonsList.classList.add("ButtonsList");

   //Done
   buttonsList.setAttribute("json" , json);
}
```

Next , I have putted buttons in the ul li and defined the listener for clicking at these buttons :

```
function clicking(){    
    var li = this.parentElement;
    // buttonsList equals to the UL keeping the json in attributes
    var buttonsList = li.parentElement;
    var json = buttonsList.getAttribute("json");
    console.log(Object.keys(json));
}
```

The json type is [object Object];
As result I have the following -

```
15) ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", 
"13", "14"]
 0: "0"
1: "1"
2: "2"
3: "3"
4: "4"
5: "5"
6: "6"
7: "7"
8: "8"
9: "9"
10: "10"
11: "11"
12: "12"
13: "13"
14: "14"
length: 15
__proto__: Array(0)
```

But , it should be like at the top of story.

Comment: Attributes can only be strings.  So if you are attempting to set an attribute with parsed json, and expect to get it out as parsed json, that's not going to work.  You will want to stringify it when you put it as an attribute, and parse it after you retrieve it from the attribute.

Comment: @Taplar , but isn't parsed json a simple string?

Comment: Absolutely not.  Parsed json becomes an object.  That's what parsing means.  It converts the string representation of an object, *into* and object.

Comment: @Taplar , I've got on.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that will help you, but in your code you already have `buttonsList` as an object, so you can set your JSON object to it directly in `prepareButtons()` function:

```
buttonsList._dummyName = json;
```

and get it in `clicking()` function like this:

```
var json = buttonsList._dummyName ;
```